# Get the elements not crawled by Google Bot

Tags: web-crawler, user-agent, robots.txt

I have a sample problem. I have a url and its html as an input and I need to get elements not allowed to be crawled by crawlers as googlebot useragent.

The file Robots.txt don't give all elements not crawled and I have a problem to detect this elements.

Do you have any idea about that ? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by elements, you mean links to resources outside the page. Have a look at [crawler-commons](https://github.com/crawler-commons/crawler-commons), it has an API for processing robots files. You'll need to fetch the robots page and after parsing it with crawler-commons, you'll be able to check whether a particular URL is allowed given a user agent.

Web crawlers such as [StormCrawler](http://stormcrawler.net/) do that by default.